# How To Prevent Navigation Loops In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

In my application I have 13 screens in total, some of them has links to other screens, I also have a drawer that has links to most of these screens.

The following image shows the only navigation flow that I want in the app:

[image]

as you can see the only screens that have links to other screens are the `home`, `warehouses` and `close expiry` screens. But because the drawer exists in every screen I now can navigate from `warehouses` to `products` then `warehouses` then `products` and so on, or from `close expiry` to `warehouses` to `products` to `home` to `close expiry` **until the end of time**.

what I want is this: whenever the user navigates to one of the `home` screen direct links, the screens stack should only contain the `home` screen and the navigated to screen with it's descendants.

In other words, I want to make sure the the screens stack has only one instance of any screen in the app. I don't want loops, and I also don't want to get rid of the drawer.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. You should use Navigator 2.0 and keep your navigation state.

Comment: you can try with navigator 2.0 or using methods from navigation 1.0 like popUntil to get back to home page and pushReplacement to get from one page from the drawer to another

Comment: @moneeralhashim thanks a lot

Comment: @pedropimont thank you so much

Comment: do you guys mean that I should use the nested routes in navigation 2.0?

Comment: no not necessarily, only if you need to. the thing about navigator 2.0 Is that it gives you full control about your page stack and enables a better experience for web, it doesn't have anything to do with nested navigation and in my opinion it's overkill for most cases , and if you don't plan on using web I would stick with navigator 1.0 since the navigator 2.0 is way more complex and boiler platy

Comment: @pedropimont ok thanks a lot man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I've found is to always navigate to the home screen before going to any other screen, this way we can achieve exactly what is asked in the question